# Pytorch Extension: difference of performance between the extension that was compiled by g++ and that was built by setuptools

Tags: c++11, python-3.6, pytorch

I wrote a cpp extension for torch which is a custom convolutional function.

Firstly, I compiled this function with g++ directly which was used for testing, the latency is **5 milliseconds**.

Secondly, I tried to integrate this function to torch and installed this extension by setuptools, following the steps shown in the tutorial provided by torch. However, the latency is now **16 milliseconds**.

The function invokation will consumes about 1-2 ms, so why the performance differs so much?

The compilation by g++ directly was done by

```
g++ -pthread -mavx2 -mfma ...
```

and the directives in the source file includes

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat"

#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT ON

#pragma GCC optimize("O3","unroll-loops","omit-frame-pointer","inline") //Optimization flags

// #pragma GCC option("arch=native","tune=native","no-zero-upper") //Enable AVX

#pragma GCC target("avx")
```

These directives were also included in the file built by setuptools. The "setup.py" file is

```
setup(
    name = 'cusconv_cpp',
    ext_modules=[
        CppExtension(name='cusconv_cpp', sources=['src/cusconv.cpp'],
        extra_compile_args={'cxx': ['-O3', '-pthread', '-mavx2', '-mfma']})
    ],
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': BuildExtension
    })
```

The output log by setuptools for buiding is

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/max/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/include -I/home/max/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/max/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/include/TH -I/home/max/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/include/THC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/indconv.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/indconv.o -O3 -pthread -mavx2 -mfma -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=indconv_cpp -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++11
```

which indeed includes those flags but many other flags were also used.
Anyone has any ideas?